# How to modify the Steam App ID using Fizzy Steamworks as editing it from Unity editor is no longer shown/available?

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamworks-api

Well, when using Fizzy Steamworks by default the Steam App ID used is 480 which is equivalent to "Spacewar" game, so how I modify it to my own Steam App ID?
I am using the most recent version of Fizzy Steamworks(FizzySteamTransport-5.0.1), and the "Steam App ID" option to set that value is no longer available, so I am wondering if I want to publish my game on Steam, and I would like to modify this value to my own Steam App ID, how do I do it as I can't do it from it? Thankss

Here is an screenshot([Old FizzySteamworks Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOMP2.png))  of the old versions of Fizzy Steamworks, notice that in the screenshot there is an option to set "Steam App ID" and it is no longer shown/available to modify it from the editor.

EDIT:
After posting the question here, I did some research and found something related at https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk/api#initialization_and_shutdown I think the answer may be there, but I appreciate some guidance on the subject.

Comment: https://steamworks.github.io/faq/ "Steam only shows me playing ‘SpaceWar’ how do I change it to my game?
When you launch your game from outside of Steam it relies on steam_appid.txt to be present to let steam know what is being launched. To change from SpaceWar to your own game you must edit the steam_appid.txt which is found in the root of your Unity project, or next to your built .exe/.app. Replace ‘480’ with your Valve provided AppId."

Comment: why did you tag this "mirror"? you don't talk about that at all.

Answer (score 0):

there have to be a txt file in your project folder, that name is "steam_appid.txt", open it and paste your game id.